# Pyenv local configuration problems

Tags: python, macos, pyenv

How does pyenv local work? I'm trying to set local version to 3.8.1, but cli run shows me that it execs on system version:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to check which pyenv you use:

```
pyenv version
```

Then set global python version:

```
pyenv global 3.8.1
```

To check which python will you run, just run command

```
python
```

Try to activate one of your pyenv virtual environments.
To see list of virtualenvs:

```
pyenv virtualenvs
```

To create a new virtualenv:

```
pyenv virtualenv venv
```

To activate virtualenv:

```
pyenv activate <name>
```

If you have issue with paths, then add these commands into your .bashrc or run in terminal:

```
$ export PATH="$HOME/.pyenv/bin:$PATH"
$ eval "$(pyenv init -)"
$ eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
```